# Uninstall resistant place to store a short string on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I know that the short answer for that question is: There is none. All app related data is deleted when uninstalling the app.

But is there a long yes answer to that question?

I tough about key chain but I think that the app entries are also deleted. Am I right ?

Thanks.

EDIT: Locally on the device.

Comment: Put it in the cloud?

Comment: I mean locally, on the device.

Comment: I would not recommend using the keychain for that. It will indeed survive an app uninstall, but this is undocumented behavior and might change without notice. 
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/36442#thread-message-112814

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, I do it all the time. To simplify things for yourself use a KeychainManager cocoapod:

```
pod 'KeychainSwift'
```

to initialize:

```
fileprivate static let keychainDeviceUUIDKey: String = "deviceUUID"
fileprivate static let keyPrefix: String = "com.you.yourapp."
fileprivate static let keychain = KeychainSwift(keyPrefix: keyPrefix)
```

An extension for storing a getting strings in keychain:

```
fileprivate extension KeychainManager {
    class func storeString(string: String, key: String) -> Bool {

        keychain.synchronizable = false

        if keychain.set(string, forKey: key) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }

    class func getString(key: String) -> String? {
        let deviceNodeName = keychain.get(key)
        return deviceNodeName
    }
}
```

usage:

```
let newDeviceId = UUID().uuidString
if KeychainManager.storeString(string: newDeviceId, key: keychainDeviceUUIDKey) {
    // all good, stored in keychain now
}
else {
    // error handling
}
```

This way even if you delete the application the value survives in the secure keychain storage and is available again once you reinstall the application.

Comment: as commented by  rraphael, this option might go away in future version of iOS. See the post by eskimo (an Apple staff member) in that thread https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/36442#thread-message-112814

Comment: that was three-four years ago and everything still works as before. and there would be deprecation notices first and we haven't even had that so I don't think we need to worry about it just yet.

Comment: I would not rely on getting deprecation notices from Apple, as the keychain was never documented to be persistent across app uninstalls. Just the opposite in fact.

Comment: I my case a changing a behaviorof keychain would not be catastrophic. Tks